# Rails 6.0: jquery 3.6.0 no more compatible with typeahead.js 0.11.0 (?)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

After jquery upgrade 3.5.1 -> 3.6.0 the error occurs:

```
TypeError: $(…).typeahead is not a function
    ...
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5430)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5234)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
```

Would jquery 3.6.0 be no longer compatible with typeahead.js 0.11.0?

Answer (score 0):

jquery 3.6.0 is compatible with typeahead.js respectively corejs-typeahead, I just missed the jQuery UI library by mistake.